# Cyclic restart my application in 3h intervals. How to?

Tags: android

I need to write an application to open the browser (sample site www.onet.pl), which will restart every 3 hours. The commotion of restart was displayed. I managed to create such a layout, but I can not handle the cyclical restart. Please help where to add and what code? One class is enough.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Object v;
Handler mHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    start(null);
    m_Runnable.run();

}

public void start(View v) {

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://onet.pl");
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(i);
    this.mHandler = new Handler();

}

private final Runnable m_Runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "odświezenie strony", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        MainActivity.this.mHandler.postDelayed(m_Runnable, 15000);


    }

};

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a timer instead of Runnable.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                 public void run() {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "odświezenie strony", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//and put the rest of your code here


        }
        },0,5000);
```

Comment: Yes that is a good idea. It works. How to quit (kill) a previous (previous) version of an open page? By default chrome writes every page opening .... after "x" calls, there will be a lot of open bookmarks. Do I set it in the browser or write in the program?

Comment: Honestly, I have never tried that with browsers @sasz87 . Try both of them and see which one works best